# MySQL Point Distance From Line in v5.6

Tags: mysql, geospatial

I have a shared hosted MySQL v5.6 table with a POINT column containing Long/Lat values. I am constructing a LineString of Long/Lat points, and want to compute a column of the distances between each POINT and the LineString. The number being returned by ST_Distance is a positive decimal, and I assume this represents the distance in degrees. However, I need the distance in meters. Since this is 5.6, I cannot use ST_Distance_Sphere, which I believe would solve the issue.

I am not totally clear on how to compute the distances manually since I do not know the second point, and I have not figured out how to query the closest point on the LineString. I also am not totally clear on how to convert the degree value being returned to meters, since I don't know the value of that second point.

Any insights on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What have you tried? Can you provide any sample data? How would you implement the ST_Distance_Sphere equation outside of MySQL?

Comment: How do I get the distance, in meters, from a line to a point?
I'm just using ST_Distance now, and I believe it's returning degrees.
I wouldn't implement it outside of MySQL. I wasn't trying to suggest that as a solution. I was more looking for a way around it returning degrees on ST_Distance.

Comment: I may be missing something, but how can you get the distance from a line to a point? Perhaps a point on a line to a different point? Either way, if MySQL 5.6 doesn't support it, you need to implement the equation yourself, either in a function, or outside of the data layer if required.

Comment: ST_Distance can use a LineString as an argument. It would be a lot better to be able to use that for the sake of efficiency, so I was hoping to find a way to just convert what I'm already getting.